# Getting error for The subdomain does not map to a valid identity zone, understanding how to define such zones on K8s

Tags: cloud-foundry, cloudfoundry-uaa

Now I have a plain K8s cluster (1.15.0) running on a set of VMs on VMWare, it is not in the cloud so I don't have a domain registered there.

what i did after installing the K8s cluster, I mapped a virtual domain in hosts file of all the vms to map to one single worker node and then I started installing uaa using such domain the public ip assigned to my single worker node (mydoman.com mypublicip).

when i installed uaa all pods are started up properly but it is not really healthy as it is giving that the readiness prob fail as it is not able to access the domain https://uaa.${DOMAIN}:8443/info

trying the same url using my local worker node ip or the public ip i am getting the following error 
The subdomain does not map to a valid identity zone.

So Can someone please explain what am I missing?